# Web API to connect Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: visual-studio-2022, webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, dynamics-crm-2016

Can I create a Web API to connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 2016 on prem using .NET Core 6.0?

I attempted to accomplish this using .NET Framework 4.7 and it was successful, however it doesn't work in .NET Core 6.0.

In .NET Core 6.0, when I try to install the necessary packages like Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk,Microsoft.Xrm.Client, an error appears indicating that these packages are compatible with .NET Framework 4.6, 4.7, 4.8.

How can I resolve this problem to create Web API using .NET Core 6.0?

Comment: Look at the Nuget package `Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/) - it's basically the .NET Core version of the CRM SDK.

Comment: This package used to connect to Microsoft Dataverse,but i want to connect to the Entities of Microsoft dynamics 365 to create CRUD web API

Comment: Dataverse **is** the "database" underlying Dynamics 365 ....